# Python 3.4.2 Popen difference on Windows vs Linux

Tags: linux, windows, popen, python-3.4

I am trying to write a python script that uses Popen to run other python scripts.  I have the functionality that I want, but I have noticed different behavior on Linux compared to Windows.  Here is the code snippet that I think is causing the difference:

```
                p = Popen([script_call, test_file], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)

                try:
                    p.wait(timeout = zombie_wait)
                    print(p.returncode)
                except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as err:
                    force_kill = True
                    p.kill()
                    zombie_thread_warning(os.path.basename(tup[0]))
                    o = open("grade.txt", "w")
                    o.write("TimeoutExpired ERROR: {0}\n".format(err))
                    o.write("PLEASE CONTACT THE INSTRUCTOR\n")  
                    o.close()
```

When I run this code on Linux, I have two files that get flagged.  On Windows there are five files that get flagged.  When I run the script that I am calling in Popen by itself, it turns out the Linux numbers (only two flagged files) is correct.  Is there something that Linux does for processes that Windows does not, and if so can I add that to my code to get the same results on both platforms?

edit: I am using the stdout and stderr from the process in Popen later in my code by using:

```
                    p.stdout
                    p.stderr
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read from the pipes if you use `PIPE` otherwise the child process may block and the timeout happens -- It is not clear whether it is the case here -- the pipe buffers may be different on different platforms, environments.

If you want to ignore the output; use `DEVNULL` instead:

```
from subprocess import DEVNULL, TimeoutExpired, call

try:
    rc = call([script_call, test_file], timeout=zombie_wait,
              stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
except TimeoutExpired as error:
    force_kill = True #XXX do you need it?
    zombie_thread_warning(os.path.basename(tup[0])) 
    with open('grade.txt', 'a') as file: # append multiple errors
        print("{test_file} timed out: {error}".format(**vars()),
              "PLEASE CONTACT THE INSTRUCTOR", sep='\n', file=file)
else:
     print("return code", rc)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  In my original code I was trying to capture stdout and stderr from the process.  Is there a way I can do this with call(), because the documentation I found said not to use pipe with this function.

Comment: @zerODoom: yes. You should not use `PIPE` with the `call()` function for the same reason that you should not just call `p.wait()` if you use `PIPE` as in your question. Either use `check_output()` or `p=Popen() + p.communicate()` if you want to capture the output.

Comment: Since I was writing stdout and stderr to a file further down the code, I just opened a file for append and passed that to stdout and stderr in call.  Having done that your advice worked and I have the same functionality on both Windows and Linux. Thanks again!

Comment: yes. Possible implementation of `DEVNULL` is just `DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)`. Obviously, you can use `logfile = open('filename', 'ab', 0)` for output streams. You could use `stdout=logfile, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` if you're redirecting both streams to the same file. You can use it with the `call()` function (the redirect is at the OS level, nothing to read here).